# MarkupExtension in ResourceDictionary.Source property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, markup-extensions

I'm trying to create a markup extension that simplifies writing URIs for the Source property of the WPF ResourceDictionary.

The minimal example of the problem is following:

**CS:**

```
public class LocalResourceExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new Uri("Resources.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="{mw:LocalResource}" /> <!-- error MC3022 -->
        <!-- <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml" /> --> <!-- Works fine -->
    </UserControl.Resources>
<!-- ... -->
</UserControl>
```

This does not compile with following error:

```
error MC3022: All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them.
```

However, if I replace a markup extension with a constant value (as shown in the commented line), everything works fine.

Why is the version with markup extension not working? Is there a workaround for it?

I'm using MSVC 2015.

Comment: Did you try putting it inside `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Great workaround, thank you. Didn't think of it. However, in this case my extension doesn't 'simplify' much, because it adds 4 more lines to every usage...

Comment: It also doesn't work at design time, so it blue-squiggles the ResourceDictionary element. Harmless but annoying. The real solution here, I think, is to just write a regular resource dictionary that merges whatever you need, and include that explicitly.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, I think I'll have to go the way without custom markup extension. Still don't get what's wrong with it. Looks like a nasty limitation of XAML compliler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
public class LocalResource : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new ResourceDictionary() { 
            Source = new Uri("Resources.xaml", UriKind.Relative) 
        };
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <myNamespace:LocalResource />
</Window.Resources>
```

The XAML editor blue-squiggles `<myNamespace:LocalResource />` at design time, which kills the Design view. So this only works if you don't use the Design view. I don't, but some do.

I keep telling my girlfriend I'm the greatest genius since Galileo, and she just doesn't believe me. Galileo would've found a way to make Design view work.

## UPDATE

Solution number two:

```
public class LocalResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary
{
    public LocalResourceDictionary()
    {
        Source = new Uri("Resources.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <myNamespace:LocalResourceDictionary />
</Window.Resources>
```

That works correctly at runtime, silences the squiggle, and allows the designer to work. However, it silently fails to merge the resource file in Design mode. Still not ideal.

## UPDATE

OP is smarter than me. This does everything:

```
public class LocalResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary
{
    public LocalResourceDictionary()
    {
        Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyName;component/Resourc‌​es.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! Second solution even works in design view, if LocalResourceDictionary provides an absolute URI (starting with pack://).

Comment: @nevermind Awesome. I tried fiddling with pack, but I couldn't get it to work. What was the exact string you were using?

Comment: `Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyName;component/Resources.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);` works for me.